# Working with session and cookies

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I have this problem or I dont know the concept of how it work, I have made a login with a remember functionallity.
I save in a cookie if the users check it, so when he enter again the web page can access directly to the main and not login again..
The problem is that when the user login as normal I save in sessions some info, but what happends when the user have the cookie of rembmber and enter directly without login at the site? I lose that session info.. what I have to do??

I wish you dont understand comment and I explain better, thanks for your time!

Comment: you'd have to check HOW the user came in, and restore any missing session data.

Comment: Why you use session ? You can use only **COOKIE** and the user's table in the database .
- You can unset the cookie after N time `setcookie("username", "blanked",time()-3600*25, '/');`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the information you're storing in the session is data related to the user, which is in turn pulled out of a database somewhere?  If that's the case, then the solution I recommend is this:

The cookie you set when the user chooses the Remember Me option needs to contain a value that will allow you to find that same user again in your database, so that you can instantiate their session the same way you would if you'd found that user through the credentials they provided at login.  It's tempting, (but insecure), to do this the easy way and simply store the unique database ID for your user information, but don't do that!

Instead, create a table called sessions, containing three columns: user_id, session_id, expire_time. When your user logs in, having set the 'Remember Me' bit to true, you'll store their user id, the session id, (obtainable by calling the session_id() function), and a time for when you'd like the 'remembered' session to expire.

When a user logs in and you add their data to your session, you can then call a function similar to this:

```
<?php
   function persist_session(){
     $user_id     = $_SESSION['user']->id;
     $session_id  = session_id();
     $expire_time = time() + (60 * 60) * 24; // 24 hours
     $sql         = "INSERT INTO sessions (user_id, session_id, expire_time), VALUES ($user_id, $session_id, $expire_time)";
     mysqli_query($sql); // This assuming you've already set up your DB connection and so on
     $_COOKIE['session_id'] = $session_id; // Write the persisted session ID to a cookie
   }
?>
```

This isn't a terribly complete example. For one thing, you'll want to write some code to ensure that no user has more than one session persisted to the table at one time, but that's easy enough...

Once you've persisted the session information and written it to a cookie for later reference, getting back the user information from the cookie is pretty straightforward:

```
<?php
    function reinstantiate_session(){
      if(isset($_COOKIE['session_id')){
        $session_info = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE session_id = '{$_COOKIE[session_id]}'")); 
        if($session_info){
          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $session_info->user_id;
        }
      }
    }
?>
```

Again, this example isn't as complete as it could be...You'll want to handle errors, and in particular, you'll probably need to update your find sql to exclude expired info, but this should be enough to get you started!